# Made a recursive program to convert the column position into an Excel column (1 = A, 27 = AA), getting @'s in my output

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, recursion, largenumber

I made this program to familiarize myself with recursion and for all intents and purposes it is working.

```
def alpha_covert(to_print):
    if to_print is 0:
        return 'Z'
    else:
        return chr(int(to_print) + 64)

def order(to_print):
    if to_print <= 26:
        return alpha_covert(to_print)
    else:
        return (str(order(to_print % 26))) + (str(order(to_print / 26)))
```

Some example outputs:

```
>>print(order(1))
>>print(order(100))
>>print(order(443))
>>print(order(9001))
>>print(order(9999999999999999))

A
VC
AQ
EHM
O@JIHYHMTURB
```

For the last output why is there a `@`? I assumed there was no issue as `int` isn't declared until I use `alpha_covert` which by then should only be `less than or equal to 26`.

Is this some kind of float rounding error?

---

Some additional samples while I'm trying to self-solve this. I don't know what this means:

```
>>print(order(9999999999999997))
>>print(order(9999999999999998))
>>print(order(9999999999999999))

M@JIHYHMTURB
N@JIHYHMTURB
O@JIHYHMTURB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that:

```
if to_print is 0:
```

happens *before you've converted `to_print` to an integer*. Also, you should really be using equality (`==`) not identity (`is`); small integers are interned in CPython, but this is an implementation detail you shouldn't rely on.

The simplest fix is:

```
if to_print == '0':  # compare to string, and by equality
```

but a better way is to convert the number first, and use the fact that zero numerical values [evaluate false-y](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

```
def alpha_convert(to_print):  # note typo in function name
    """A docstring would be nice, too!"""
    to_print = int(to_print)
    return chr(to_print + 64) if to_print else 'Z'
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, I'm still getting the same outputs.

Comment: @AndyWong sure? `alpha_covert('0')` worked fine for me after the edit, and `order(9999999999999999) == 'OZJIHYHMTURB'`. I've added another, more idiomatic alternative.

Comment: Thank you this worked. Can you refer me to documentation for this syntax? I'm not entirely familiar with what this does. `return chr(to_print + 64) if to_print else 'Z'`